# declaring a function returning a 2 d array in c

Tags: c

This question is asked in some ways but am finding it difficult to understand.

`int (*q)[3][4]` -> `q` is a pointer to a 2-D array of 3 rows and 4 columns.

Now suppose I want to return a 2-d array from a function.

```
pointer-to-2d-array  func() {

     static 2 day array;

     return ;
}
```

Basically what should be the signature of my function. I have seen many places like below which I dont undesrtand

```
int (*fun2())[column];
```

Am finding it difficult to explain/understand the signature . 
Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Please use [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=) before asking questions.

Comment: `void func(int (*p)[][COL_SIZE])` should do it. Note that row size is optional, which could automatically be evaluated. An array is passed to a function as a pointer, the changes in callee will reflect in caller too. So `void` as return type makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach is to use `typedef`:

```
typedef int (*ThreeByFourPtr)[3][4];

ThreeByFourPtr fun() {
    static int res[3][4]= {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
    return &res;
}
```

The advantage is that the syntax mirrors that of type pointer declaration, with type name replacing the name of the variable.